# ViewPagers in ListView: onItemClickListener

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` which shows `ViewPager`s as row elements. I want to use an `OnItemClickListener`, but the `ViewPager` prevents `onItemClick` from being called. How can I do this?

Comment: Have found a solution? android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" did not work for me. mViewpager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false); won't work as well since I don't want to disallow touch events on the view pager at all.

Comment: convertView.setOnClickListener(new ListItemClickListener());

private class ListItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {}

}

Answer (score 0):

Interesting setup. The problem is that the ViewPager has "stolen" focus from the actual list element.

When initially returning your list item view, (e.g. in your ListAdapter), call `setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)` on that view.

Or, add this directly to your list element's XML layout: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

This problem description & solution has been found [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414#c27).

Answer (score 0):

Use `mViewpager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);` to disallow the ViewPager to intercept the event from the ListView.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a custom ListView implementation like the one in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051801/425238

Answer (score -2):

your setup sounds rather confusing but what it sounds like you want is a way to monitor ViewPager page changes, in which case you would use the following

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        //actions
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //actions
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        //actions
    }
});
```

from what it sounds like onPageSelected sounds like your best bet, you can use this to get the currently selected page index.

However if you want to get when Items in your list view are selected you need something like this.

```
ListView listview;
listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //on item selected here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //never had to implement personally
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not about page changes, it's about a single tap on the viewpager that should cause the onitemclick to be called. Each row contains a viewpager.

Comment: ah ok, I edited my answer to reflect what you're looking for which is OnItemSelected (rather then onItemClick)