# ViewPager inside ListView row prevents onItemClick to be fired

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager inside every row of a ListView. It works fine, it changes the views inside it when the user use the swipe gesture, but it prevents the ListView's onItemClick method to be called. I know that the ViewPager is the culprit because when I hide it, the onItemClick is called, so this is what I am trying:

I have created a ViewGroup to be the row (RowView). This ViewGroup has `onInterceptTouchEvent` overriden to avoid the ViewPager to handle further touch events when I detect a click. But the onItemClick callback is still not being called. And the list selector doesn't show either on click. I want this two features to work.

This is how the onInterceptTouchEvent from RowView looks like:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int actionMasked = ev.getActionMasked();
    switch(actionMasked) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("RowView", "OnInterceptTouchEvent - Down");
            tapDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
            return false;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.d("RowView", "OnInterceptTouchEvent - Cancel");
            tapDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(tapDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)) {
                Log.d("RowView", "OnInterceptTouchEvent - UP!");
                return true;
            }
            break;
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

**EDIT**: Not working example about how the onItemClick in MainActivity is not called when the ViewPager is active (Lollipop list selector doesn't appear either)

> MainActivity

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);
listView.setAdapter(new MainListAdapter(this, 30));
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: " + position);
    }
});
```

> List item XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/row_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> List adapter:

```
public class MainListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int count;

    public MainListAdapter(Context context, int count) {
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = createRow(parent, holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(Integer.toString(position));
        int randomPages = (int) (new Random().nextDouble()*5+2);
        holder.viewPager.setAdapter(new NumAdapter(context, randomPages));

        return convertView;
    }

    private View createRow(ViewGroup parent, ViewHolder holder) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_main_listview, parent, false);
        holder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_num);
        holder.viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.row_viewpager);
        view.setTag(holder);

        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
        public ViewPager viewPager;
    }
}
```

> ViewPager's Adapter:

```
public class NumAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int count;

    public NumAdapter(Context context, int count) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_viewpager, container, false);
        textView.setText("Page " + position);
        container.addView(textView);
        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can intercept the call from the ViewPager, and perform your action?

Comment: @jyoon I'm sorry, but that breaks the encapsulation principle. Besides that, you cannot register an onClick in the ViewPager because it doesn't work (I guess it's related to the issue I have). Thanks anyway.

Comment: How about the image inside your viewpager?

Comment: @jyoon Yes, there you can put click listeners, but, how can I communicate with the ListView so the ripples appear in the selector of the ListView and the onItemClickListener is fired? I tried that but not working as expected.

Comment: @jyoon You mean inside the ViewPager? If the ListView doesn't notice about the click, the selector is not shown. That's the problem. If I put a ripple drawable inside the ViewPager, it is going to be below another elements of the ListView row, but I guess that if I cannot get it working like I want, I'll try to simulate the ListView behavior inside the ViewPager. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post more details about your `ListView`?

Comment: Is the `ViewPager` only showing one `ImageView` per page, or are there other views in the layout?

Comment: @Adrian: I'd like to help, but damn I'm lost..I read about you having ImageViews in your ViewPager, but I see TextView in the snipper you provided..:)

Comment: @simekadam Well, that's because the code I put is a sample of what I'm trying to do. The problem is the ViewPager, and it's the same if you put TextViews inside it or ImageViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done finally to manage this although the list selector doesn't work. This could be improved, but, for now, it is the only workaround that I like how it works.

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    /*
     *  Used for detect taps
     */
    private GestureDetector tapDetector;
    /*
     *  As we need to set our own OnScrollListener, this stores the one 
     *  used outside, if any
     */
    private OnScrollListener onScrollListener;

    private boolean isScrolling = false;

    public CustomListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initView(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initView(context);
    }

    private void initView(Context context) {
        tapDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new TapListener());
        super.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener onScrollListener) {
        this.onScrollListener = onScrollListener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean isTap = tapDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        if(ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // Don't perform the click if the ListView is scrolling
            // so it is able to stop the scroll
            if(isTap && !isScrolling && hasOnItemClickListener()) {
                int itemPosition = pointToPosition((int)ev.getX(), (int)ev.getY());
                performItemClick(this, itemPosition, getItemIdAtPosition(itemPosition));
            }
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public boolean hasOnItemClickListener() {
        return getOnItemClickListener() != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        isScrolling = scrollState != OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

        if(this.onScrollListener != null) {
            onScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if(this.onScrollListener != null) {
            onScrollListener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think better override listview onintercepter than viewgroup.

TouchEvent Flow simply :

Acitivity touch event - > viewgroup.dispatchtouchevent -> viewgroup.intercepter..-> view.dispatchtouch... -> .....

in this case list.dispatch call. toss event to `ViewPager.dispatch`. but before `ViewPager.dispatchtouchevent`, call `ListView.intercepterTouchEvent`.

if `dispatchTouchEvent` return `false` call parent `View`'s `TouchEvent` but return `true` call flow descent.

if `intercepterTouchEvent` return `true` don't calling child `dispatchTouchEvent` but return `false` calling child `dispatchTouchEvent`.
so `listview.intercepterTouchEvent` return `true`, calling o`nItemClick`.

so if `listView.intercepterTouchEvent` return `true`, not swiped `viewPager` items.

you can know user's action swipe or click 2 way.
`TouchEvent` and `guesturedetector`..

in listview's `IntercepterTouchEvent(Event ev);`

```
VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
PointF mLastPoint;
public mListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public mListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public mListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    mLastPoint = new PointF();
}


@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if(mVelocityTracker == null)
        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);

    switch (ev.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(100);
            int x = (int)Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity());
            int move_x = (int)Math.abs(ev.getX() - mLastPoint.x);
            Log.d("ListView","speed : " + x +" move_x : " + move_x);
            //here x is drag speed. (pixel/s)
            // change value left right both value you want speed and move amount
            if(move_x < 100 || x <100) {
                mLastPoint.set(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mLastPoint.set(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            mVelocityTracker.recycle();mVelocityTracker = null;

            break;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

you can swipe speed about 100 or move amount 100 pixel. if not perform click event.

i hope this text can help you......

and add edit some code blow.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if(mVelocityTracker == null)
        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);

    switch (ev.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(10);
            int x = (int)Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity());
            int move_x = (int)Math.abs(ev.getX() - mLastPoint.x);
            int move_y = (int)Math.abs(ev.getY() - mLastPoint.y);
            Log.d("ListView","speed : " + x +" move_x : " + move_x + " move_y : "+ move_y);
            if(move_x < move_y || x < 10) {
                mLastPoint.set(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
                return true;
            }else if(move_x > move_y){
                return false;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mLastPoint.set(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d("ListView", "dispatch");
    switch (ev.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(mVelocityTracker != null){mVelocityTracker.recycle();mVelocityTracker = null;}
            break;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying your solution and it is the only one that seems to partially work. The problem with your solution is that it only works if the finger moves. If it doesn't move, the click is not fired. Besides that, even if you move a lot the finger, the click is still performed, and I think that is not how the clicks work. I've tried to modify your solution to achieve what I want, but without success. I tried to move the code below the ACTION_MOVE to the ACTION_UP, but nothing happens even if it returns true. I guess that is because it has to intercept the touch before the UP. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I got it working so the click is not fired when you swipe the ViewPager, but the only problem now is that the click is not fired unless the user moves the finger a little. If the user doesn't move the finger, ACTION_MOVE is not fired and since the ACTION_UP event doesn't have any code to intercept the touch event, the click is not fired. I have put the same code that handles ACTION_MOVE inside the ACTION_UP and although I return true, nothing happens.

Comment: oh........ achieve intercept before dispatchTouchEvent, and if dispatchTouchEvent return false, view's parent intercept touch event. return true descent event child, and child dispatchTouchEvent. of course ACTION_UP not achieve. if your want sensitive touch perform, override dispatchTouchEvent.        now i'm not in home. i'm go home make sure this issue.

Comment: now i get what is. i try explain it, but i don't know you can understand. onclick achieve when ACTION_UP. you can feel finger not move not onclick achieve. and of course ACTION_UP is not happen in IntercepterTouchEvent. because called ACTION_MOVE, achieve onTouchEvent and scrolling method. i don't know detail. and Edit some code, and add some code. it simple, not perfect. if you want to some perform when ACTION_UP, put in dispatchTouch.

Comment: in touch sense detect some action on device, first called Activity `dispatchTouchEvent`, next called root Layout's(A) `dispatchTouchEvent`. if root Layout's have children, called children(B) `dispatchTouhEvent`. if B haven't children, call A's `intercepterTouchEvent`. but have child, call B's child `dispatchEvent`. anyway, called A's `IntercepterTouchEvent` return `true`, achieve A's `onTouchEvent` and called A's `onClickperform`. but return 'false', B's `onTouhEvent`. if `dispatchTouchEvent` return `false`, it block this view's touch Event  and All descent child `TouchEvent`.

Comment: I've post an answer with your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: this solution is perfect thatnks @이남웅

Answer (score 3):

As your viewpaper is your listview's child,its consuming the touch events. You can prevent this by making your viewpagers child unclickable,i.e.

```
    TextView textView =(TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_viewpager,container, false);

    textView.setText("Page " + position); 

    textView.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to set `OnClickListener` on each `ViewPager` instance itself and avoid usage of `onItemClickListener` of the ListView. You can then completely remove `onInterceptTouchEvent()` too. That would be the simplest and stable solution. Less code - less bugs ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do one of the following:

Set a `setOnClickListener` on the `Viewpager`'s child or find

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: I already tried android:descendantFocusability="blockDescendants", but it didn't work. I guess it's because the ViewPager handle the touch events even if it hasn't receive the focus.

About setting setOnClickListener on ViewPager children, how can I trigger the ListView's onItemClick from there? I prefer to get this working as it should be, this way the selector in Lollipop would work with the ripples.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: then, modify dispatchtouchevent or interceptertetouchevent at viewpager.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I'm afraid that I didn't understand how that methods work. I only got working the ViewPager swipe or the ListView onItemClick, but never both.

Comment: I've edited my question with onInterceptTouchEvent overriden. Could you review that?

Comment: how does this answer help the person asking it?

Comment: sorry. but this question owner edit this question.
this answer replied before edited now.
please read above answer. after edit question I do re-answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick.

```
viewPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried that when initializing the viewPager in the adapter, but it didn't work. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to do the click listener on the view pager and not the listView

When adding the viewPager in the getView method, set its tag to be the position of the row

```
holder.viewPager.setTag(position);
```

Then add the click listener to the viewPager (also in getView)

```
viewPager.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = v.getTag();
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: " + position);

        //Fire a delegate or notification of whatever you want to do on the item click. You now have the position
        myClickListener.onItemClicked(position);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the list adapters viewholder. I had a similar issue when i was trying to implement same feature (viewpager inside a listview row). I resolved it by doing this----
Set the onclicklistener on viewholder object instead of setting on listview directly. To do this you have to implement onitemclicklistener on your adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

An improvement over Adrian's answer:

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public CustomListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new CustomListViewOnGestureListener());
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new CustomListViewOnGestureListener());
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new CustomListViewOnGestureListener());
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new CustomListViewOnGestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private class CustomListViewOnGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent ev) {
            int firstVisiblePosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int itemPosition = pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY());
            int childIndex = itemPosition - firstVisiblePosition;
            View view = getChildAt(childIndex);
            performItemClick(view, itemPosition, getItemIdAtPosition(itemPosition));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```